# Login Page redirection error in PHP codeignitor project

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I downloaded a CodeIgniter project from GitHub and hosted on localhost using XAMPP. Now when I am running it, it's showing me a login page, when I enter correct username password it's redirecting me to `http://localhost/project/authlogincheck`. It's giving me this error `404 Page Not Found`. There is no file like `authlogincheck` in the project.  It should be redirected to `http://localhost/project/application/views/dashboard`.

I downloaded it from [GitHub](https://github.com/hiten0794/MLM-Application-in-php/tree/master/mlm). I am not giving code here as you guys can easily view all the files of this project from GitHub.

What is the possible solution for this problem? I am new to CodeIgniter and PHP.

Here is database info.

```
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',

'username' => 'jason',
'password' => 'quarks321',
'database' => 'mlmdb',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

);

Comment: Did you create database?

Comment: Yes Shahidul bhai, i have created the database.

Comment: According to his code this should redirect you to http://localhost/v3/dashboard, so something is going wrong in the login function. Can you confirm your database is filled at all? Also try running composer install. This project has no decent readme about how to use it so it will be hard to help properly.

Comment: @killstreet ya i saw that too. In his Youtube video, its redirected to v3/dashboard after login. IDK why he changed it. Can you suggest me some thing so that i can change redirected url? i try to change it but got no success. Its not letting me access other directories.

Comment: Honestly it's very conflicting with what you said about the redirect and what his online code shows. Are you 100% sure you linked the right code? On github there is only 1 branch and 1 commit so it never changed there. Is your code somehow different from his?

Comment: I am sure you are missing .htaccess file

Comment: @BheruLalLohar He shouldn't be missing this file if he used git clone. The project itself has .htaccess file in it. These will be copied along during a copy. Even downloading a zipfile will have the .htaccess file

Comment: @killstreet true but (.)dot files are something ignored

Comment: @killstreet i have linked the right GitHub code. Maybe this guy changed his code before or after uploading the YouTube video.  Can you tell me where look for url redirection? and why its redirecting to "/authlogincheck"?

Comment: application/controllers/AdminLoginController.php is where you can find the code for the login. application/config/routes.php is where you can find all routes he made.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess file (if the file doesn't exist create one at the root of the project )

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / # project document root

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I have .htaccess file and the code you provided is also same. Can you tell me whats wrong with this thing and why its redirecting to /authlogincheck instead of localhost/v3/dashboard

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by creating a `web.config` file with following contents and place it in the root of your project

[image: Web.Config]